# how can I trigger a JList when press @ in a JTable's row in swing?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlist, keyevent

I need to trigger a JList with items when I press @ in a JTable's row in Swing, when the user selects an item the JList should disappear,  anyone know how I can achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Just curious, why the requirement for the @ symbol? Would you not want the user to see the valid options in another scenerio?

Comment: Yes, the "@" is only an example, I need to trigger the list when the user press a special symbol.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example in the tutorials for that exact scenario: [Using A Combobox As A Table Editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox).  You could trigger the start of the editor (via the @ symbol) with [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: The example has no relation with the scenario described.

Comment: `The example has no relation with the scenario described` Oh, so you *already know* how to use a combobox as a table cell editor? Great.  I must've missed that in the OP.  Now you just need to apply the KeyBindings for the "@" symbol and you're all set

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the KeyPressed event? You should be able to see if the @ has then been entered, then show the JList.

Comment: -1 there is no `onKeyPress` event. Even if there was you should be using `Key Bindings` with Swing.

Comment: Sorry I mean KeyPressed. Key bindings is probably the best way, forgot about them!